# Convert time in Local from a API

Tags: ios, json, swift, time

I am new in this and I have been stack a bit about the most "correct way" to solve this !

I am getting results from a weather API.
The response header says : "Date": "Mon, 07 Aug 2017 23:07:58 GMT"

So I guess the rest of the results-time will be in GMT time zone ?( correct me if I am wrong?

What I am trying to do is to have a scrollView that will  show the same time what's the weather in other cities for example.
now my weather is blabla time 15:00

now in  NY time is 20:00 20° , 21:00 23° etc( similar with apple weather app)

on the json I have 2 time results 
**"time_epoch": 1502089200,
"time": "2017-08-07 00:00",**

My understanding is that I have to parse the API dictionary and save the results "time" with 2 values. One with exactly as it is(as Date to TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT") and a second with the conversion to the TimeZone.current as Date again so I can compare it with my current Date on the phone.

Check then the converted time with current and print the equivalent results.

1) is that the most "correct" way ?
2) if yes , how to you convert the "time" string to local as Date.(I have tried and It always fails)
3) I am open to suggestions , I am new here

This is what I am passing in every "time" while I am parsing the API.
findCurrentHour() I am checking with my date where there are

```
func findCurrentHour() -> Int{

        var i = 0
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        if var hour = weatherHourArray[i]._time{
        while dateToday >= hour  {
            i += 1
            hour = weatherHourArray[i]._time
        }
        }
        return i

    }


extension DateFormatter {
    func date(apiDateString :String) -> Date? {
        self.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
        self.timeZone = TimeZone.current

        return self.date(from:apiDateString)
    }


    func dateOfLocal(apiDateString :String) -> Date? {
        self.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"

        return self.date(from:apiDateString)
    }

}
```

result is 2017-08-08 05:06:00 +0000 when it should be "2017-08-08 07:06"

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is a bit vague in its current form. Please provide some context by showing the `code that you have tried`, `what was the expected outcome?`, and `what outcome did you get?`

Comment: Time epoch `1502089200` works out to `2017-08-07 07:00:00 GMT`. The local time varies depending on your timezone. What is the expected result here?

Comment: can I please see your tried code so I can see your present result and make it to expected result . question is bit unclear to me

Comment: I updated my question.